# defining a new function in nodejs throws reference error

Tags: node.js

i have a .js file as follows:

```
module.exports = {
    metadata: () => ({
        "name": "HrScheduleApi",
        "properties": {
             "scheduleDate": {"type": "string", "required": false}
        }
    }),
    invoke: (conversation, done) => {
        var actionType = conversation.properties().actionType;
        logger.info("start of HrScheduleApi with action type:" + actionType);

       if(isBeyondThreeDays(scheduleDate)  == false){
                dayFromNow = '2 days from now';
                var tomorrow = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 48 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
                schDate = tomorrow.toDateString();
             }else{
                 console.log('asked schedule is beyond 48 hours');
             }
    }, 
    isBeyondThreeDays: (scheduleDate) => {
        // ...
    }
};
```

so when i needed a new function (isBeyondThreeDays) in my invoke function i just defined as below. but seems nodejs does not like it. I get the error
at run time as:

```
Error in component, details={}
ReferenceError: isBeyondThreeDays is not defined
```

Comment: Could you show how you import this module and invoke the function.

Comment: The error you show is in how you are calling `obj.isBeyondThreeDays()` so we need to see the calling code where the actual error occurs.  In the future, please always show the exact error message and the line of code where the error occurs and then relevant context.

Comment: modified the code to show how i was calling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this one

```
if(isBeyondThreeDays(scheduleDate)  == false){
```

should be

```
if(module.exports.isBeyondThreeDays(scheduleDate)  == false){
```

Or

```
const myModule = { ... your methods}
```

and

```
if(myModule.isBeyondThreeDays(scheduleDate)  == false){

...

module.exports = myModule
```